# Google Sheets nested search, looking to not include certain keyword

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Sorry if that title doesn't make sense, here is the formula I'm working with:

```
=filter(Data!A:K, search("Teton", Data!F:F), search("Case", Data!F:F))
```

But I need to not include data in the F column with the word "Case".

I tried these, but none of them work:

```
<>search("Case", Data!F:F)
search(<>"Case", Data!F:F)
```

Hopefully that will explain what I'm going for. I need to pull the rows that have the word "Teton" and don't have the word "Case". Happy to provide any other details.

Edit: Here is what the data looks like

```
Date    Date    Area    Event   Event ID    Product Title   Employee Name   Customer Name   Qty Change  Qty Reserved    Total Qty                                                               

6/2/21 17:50    6/2/2021    Till    Transaction - Return    102056948   Gibraltar Hi-Hat Clutch Curt Gordon Toby Middlebrook    1   0   1

6/2/21 14:14    6/2/2021    Till    Transaction - Sold  102046546   .50 Cent Pick   Devin Ward      -4  0   -357
```

So some of the data I need (the ones that have Teton in column F), that looks like this:

```
3/16/21 13:30   3/16/2021   Other   Other   79515628    Teton STG100NT Acoustic Guitar  -   -   -1  0   1
```

But if I only search by Teton, I'll get cases in as well, which look like this:

```
3/16/21 14:15   3/16/2021   Till    Transaction - Sold  99059660    Teton Classical/Concert Arched Hard Case    Curt Gordon     -1  0   0
```

And I don't want anything with the word "case" in column F.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't given us much to go on, since we don't know anything about your actual data, ranges, whether your `SEARCH`es are `AND` or `OR`, or what your full end goal may be. However, I can tell you that one way to negate a `SEARCH` (i.e., to see if X is *not* found) is as follows:

`=ISERROR(SEARCH("Case", Data!F:F))`

Comment: Hi! I've updated my post with more info. Thanks for the response!

Comment: Yes, your full formula then would be as follows: =FILTER(Data!A:K, SEARCH("Teton", Data!F:F), ISERROR(SEARCH("Case", Data!F:F)))

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=QUERY(Data!A:K, "where lower(F) contains 'teton' 
                and not lower(F) contains 'case'")
```

[image]

Comment: Gave me back a "No matches are found in filter evaluation"